# Excel function changed to CSE doesn't work like eariler

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel workbook that I'm tring to convert to CSE, since it has a lot of repeating functions and want to lower size of the file. Most of them worked, but I have problem with one (it's mostly logic):

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(H4 ="";NOT(L4 =""));N4 /0,8; VLOOKUP (I4;'Karta projektu'!$I$7:$J$12;2;FALSE)*H4);"")
```

When applied to every separate cell function works properly. So i changed it to CSE function like this:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(H4:H1003="";NOT(L4:L1003=""));N4:N1003/0,8; VLOOKUP (I4:I1003;'Karta projektu'!$I$7:$J$12;2;FALSE)*H4:H1003);"")
```

And it is not working properly. Below is explenation of what I'm trying to archive:

First, if **H** is empty and **L** is not empty, I want to display modified **N** value, else I want to display **H** value multiplied by looked up value from another sheet (it's basicly choosing currency exchenge rate). *IFERROR* is for not displaying anything if some of data is missing.

So the part with *VLOOKUP* is working fine. Now if i leave **H** empty and put something in **L**, cell displays 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [AND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-5F19B2E8-E1DF-4408-897A-CE285A19E9D9) does not work well in array formulas (aka CSE). Nest a couple of IF statements to get the desired result.

```
=IFERROR(IF(H4:H1003=""; IF(L4:L1003<>""; N4:N1003/0,8; VLOOKUP(I4:I1003; 'Karta projektu'!$I$7:$J$12; 2; FALSE)*H4:H1003)); "")
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I had to add one more VLOOKUP to first IF false statement but now it works in CSE.